# Minimum number of jumps to reach end of the array with sequence using recursion

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, c++14, dynamic-programming

I have a code for "Minimum number of jumps to reach end of the array with its sequence using recursion". **But I am not able to print the sequence.** ( There is nothing in vector vec to print )
Any help will be appreciated.

> Explanation :
>    I want to reach from 1st element ( i.e. 2) to
>   last element ( i.e. 4) of the array in **minimum Jump**.
>       How Jump will be :
>             1st element is 2. It means I can make upto 2 jumps in array. If I take 1st jump then I can reach 2nd element ( i.e. 3) or if I take
>   2nd jump then I can reach 3rd element (i.e. 1)
>          2nd element is 3 ,so I can make maximum 3 jumps. In 1st jump I can reach to 1 , in 2nd jump I can reach to 0 and in 3rd jump I can
>   reach to 4
>           In this way I want to reach from 1st element to last element of the array in **minimum number of jumps.**
>           So output will be like , from 1st element 2, I will jump to 3. Then from 3 I will jump to 4 (last element). So 2 Jumps. ( 2 - 3 - 4 )

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<climits>
using namespace std;

int jump(int arr[], int n, int start, vector<int> &vec)
{
    if(start == n-1)  // if start is the last element in array
       return 0;

    if( arr[start] == 0)  // if array element is 0 
       return 0;

    vector<int> vec1 = vec;
    vector<int> vec2 = vec;

    int minimum = INT_MAX;
    for( int i = 1 ; i <= arr[start]; i++ )
    {
        vec1.push_back(start);

        int _jump = 1 + jump( arr, n, start+i, vec1); // considering every jump 

        vec = (_jump < minimum) ? vec1 : vec2;

        minimum = min(minimum, _jump);
    }
        return minimum;

}

int main()
{
    int arr[] = { 2, 3, 1, 0, 4 };
    int n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);

    vector<int> vec;
    cout << "Number of jumps " << jump(arr, n, 0, vec) << endl;
    cout<<"Sequence is "<<endl;
    for( auto x : vec)
        cout << x <<" ";  
    return 0;
}
```

output

```
Number of jumps 2      
Sequence is
```

Expected output

```
 Number of jumps 2       
 Sequence is 2 3 4
```

Comment: Could you please explain the algorithmic problem you are trying to solve? It might help us. Also provide the full code so we will be able to execute it. Finally, what is the output that you do get and have you tried to debug?

Comment: In `jump`, every time you choose not to adjust `minimum`, you nevertheless discard the accumulated list of jumps, by way of `vec = vec2;`

Comment: I think this problem needs some more debugging work on your part before it is ready for SO. Try to simplify the situation. For example, the current example uses a 10-element array. Can you demonstrate the problem with only 9 elements? 8? How short can you make it? After shortening your input, debug `jump`. Check the values of `vec`, `vec1`, and `vec2` at the end of each loop iteration (don't forget to account for the recursion). Are the values what you expect based upon your algorithm? Can you narrow down the problem?

Comment: @Yonlif I have tried to explain the problem. I tried to debug and I found that my vector vec size is 0. I pushed in vector vec , but still size is 0.

Comment: @JaMiT I have narrowed down the problem. I tried to debug but vector vec.size() is 0. That's why in output 2nd line is showing nothing.

Comment: Shouldn't this `if( arr[start] == 0)` return `infinity` since we cannot complete the sequence?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example that will set a vector where each index stores the correct next step in the sequence after visiting that index. I leave it to you to code following the sequence from the first element to the end, using the result vector. I also corrected this condition `if( arr[start] == 0)` to return "infinity" since if we visit this element, we cannot complete the sequence.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<climits>
using namespace std;

int jump(int arr[], int n, int start, vector<int> &vec)
{
    if(start == n-1)  // if start is the last element in array
       return 0;

    if( arr[start] == 0)  // if array element is 0 
       return INT_MAX - n;

    int minimum = INT_MAX;
    int step;
    for( int i = 1 ; i <= arr[start]; i++ )
    {
        int _jump = 1 + jump( arr, n, start+i, vec); // considering every jump 

        if (_jump < minimum){
          minimum = _jump;
          step = start + i;
        }
    }

    vec.at(start) = step;

    return minimum;
}

int main()
{
    int arr[] = { 2, 3, 1, 0, 4 };
    int n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);

    vector<int> vec(n, -1);
    cout << "Number of jumps " << jump(arr, n, 0, vec) << endl;
    cout<<"Vector: "<<endl;
    for( auto x : vec)
        cout << x <<" ";  
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: While you have found some of problems, the output of your code is `1 4 3 -1 -1`. possibilities. Indexes should be `0, 1, 4` thus one item miss at the beginning and one too much at the end. Also it seems that values should be displayed insdea of indexes. By the way `step` is not initialized on all path.

Comment: @Phil1970 nope, `1 4 3 -1 -1` is correct. As I described in my answer, each value in the vector is representing the next index we jump to from the index the value is stored at. In this case we start at index 0 of the vector, which tells us the next index is 1, where we find 4, which is the end of the sequence.

Comment: @Phil1970 as you suggest, there might be some unhandled edge scenarios, which I would leave for the reader to fix.

Comment: **(1)** Look at the **expected output** in the question! **(2)** What does the `3` represent in your sequence?

Comment: @Phil1970 your critique is not appropriate. I presented a method for the OP to store the sequence. I also advised the OP that it's up to them to use this method to output whatever form this sequence needs to take in a complete solution.

Comment: @Phil1970 in this answer, I did not provide a complete solution. I tried to help the OP without completing their assignment.

Comment: In that case, you should have modified the part of the code that output `Sequence is` to something like `Indexes are … Printing sequence left to OP`. Not everyone will read the text above the answer.

Comment: @Phil1970 fair enough :) Amended.

Answer (score 0):

*Essentially, this is the minimal fix so that the sample data would works. I have not check all edge cases. For example, one might want to print something else than the value of `INT_MAX` is the end is not reachable.*

**Problem 1**

You want to output values (i.e. 2, 3, 4 in your example) and not index (0, 1, 4). Thus you must push values instead of indexes.

```
vec1.push_back(arr[start]);
```

**Problem 2**

```
if(start == n-1)  // if start is the last element in array
   return 0;
```

This will not add the final value when the end is reached. You must add last value with:

```
vec.push_back(arr[start]);
```

**Problem 3**

```
if( arr[start] == 0)  // if array element is 0 
   return 0;
```

A sequence that does not reach the end, would be considered to be very good. You should return a large value. Since `_jump` is 1 + return value of `jump`, the return value should be `INT_MAX - 1` and minimum should also be initialized to that value for same reason.

Alternatively, you could return other values like `n` too instead.

**Problem 4**

Finally, the following condition is incorrect:

```
vec = (_jump < minimum) ? vec1 : vec2;
```

When the condition is not verified, it is `vect2` that need to be copied in `vec1` since the loop uses `vect1`.

Comment: I understood 1st 3 problems which you mentioned. I made a mistake. But I could not understand the last one. I tried what you said but output did not change.  Will you help me to understand  it ? What changes should I perform ?

Comment: The loop use `vec1` which should be the original value each time you do an iteration. So when the condition is not verified (not found a minimum), vec1 need to be reset to its original state (that is the copy that was made into `vec2`. Thus, you need something like `if (_jump < minimum) vec = vec1; else vec1 = vec2; `. That will get the expected output.